# Android Espresso testing withHint doesn't work

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I am currently trying to add Espresso UI testing to my Android application and I want to be able to target a TextInputEditText via it's Hint field and then click on it and enter in some text. (I know it's better practice to target ids but I need to target hint in this instance)

Here is how I have tried to do this:

```
Espresso.onView(Matchers.allOf(Matchers.instanceOf(TextInputEditText::class.java),
            ViewMatchers.withHint("My Hint"))).
            perform(ViewActions.click(), ViewActions.typeText("type this"))
```

However when trying to execute this I get the following error:

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: (an instance of android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText and with hint: is "Old Password")

Even though the output shows that the hierarchy actually does hold this view as follows:

> **TextInputEditText**{id=2131820762, res-name=input_data, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1328, height=168, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=true, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=true, editor-info=[inputType=0x80091 imeOptions=0x8000005 privateImeOptions=null actionLabel=null actionId=0 initialSelStart=0 initialSelEnd=0 initialCapsMode=0x0 hintText=**My Hint** label=null packageName=null fieldId=0 fieldName=null extras=null hintLocales=null contentMimeTypes=null ], x=0.0, y=0.0, text=, input-type=524433, ime-target=true, has-links=false}

Is the ViewMatchers.withHint method broken in Espresso or is there a particular way to use it? Why would it fail to find the view but then in the output actually show it is in the hierarchy?

Comment: Any reason that you can't remove the instanceOf() matcher and use just the withHint() one?  When writing Espresso tests, I try to keep implementation details out of them so that they're more flexible as the underlying implementation changes.  This is also important if you use the support libraries where the underlying classes that accomplish the same behavior are often different based on OS variants.

Comment: Issue is still the same if I just use withHint() I'm afraid.

Comment: Make sure that hint is shown when you open app manually. Espresso is not looking for hintText attribute you see in your output (hintText is part of editor-info), but you should also have attribute "hint=My Hint" (for me it is positioned between "text=" and "input-type"). Also, try to see in debug what is value of that textView.getHint(), because that is the value hint matcher looks for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug open for this already. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37139118

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, and found no solution on stackoverflow. My hypothesis is that the hint is of a `CharSequence` that doesn't *match* the expected string. So that, I think the hint needs to be converted to string before matching. Using `hasToString` works for me.

```kotlin
    onView(allOf(
        instanceOf(TextInputEditText::class.java),
        withHint(hasToString("My Hint"))
    )).perform(click(), typeText("type this"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The printing in your Logcat may be misleading. If your `TextInputEditText` is a child view of `TextInputLayout` with hint is enabled, the `TextInputLayout` will set the same hint internally on itself via [TextInputLayout.setHint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout#sethint), then set the hint on `TextInputEditText` to null.

You need to create a custom matcher to match hints of `TextInputEditText` as workaround:

```
fun withHint(title: String): Matcher<View> = withHint(equalTo(title))

fun withHint(matcher: Matcher<String>): Matcher<View> = object : BoundedMatcher<View, TextInputEditText>(TextInputEditText::class.java) {
    override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
        description.appendText("with hint: ")
        matcher.describeTo(description)
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: TextInputEditText): Boolean {
        val parent = item.parent.parent
        return if (parent is TextInputLayout) matcher.matches(parent.hint) else matcher.matches(item.hint)
    }
}
```

And just replace your `ViewMatchers.withHint("My Hint")` to `TextInputEditTextCustomMatchers.withHint("My Hint")`.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working for me. It's pointing towards yet another Espresso bug that most likely wont be fixed as stated by mark w.